# Undefined references to swscale functions

Tags: c++, c, qt, ffmpeg, linker

My app fails to link to swscale library at all. I mean that any swscale method I'm trying to use in my code becomes an undefined reference.
I know what this error means - a linker couldn't find any definition of used functions.

But the problem is that I made sure that:

1. `-L/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2/lib -lswscale` is in linker output, and the linker actually finds the lib, otherwise it would complain about missing `swscale`
2. The library is really there:

   `$ll /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2/lib/libswscale*`

output:

```
-r--r--r--  1 myuser  admin   519K Nov 20 19:33 /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2/lib/libswscale.3.1.101.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin    24B Nov 20 19:32 /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2/lib/libswscale.3.dylib -> libswscale.3.1.101.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 myuser  admin   607K Nov 20 19:32 /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2/lib/libswscale.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  admin    24B Nov 20 19:32 /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2/lib/libswscale.dylib -> libswscale.3.1.101.dylib
```

3. The library is of the correct architecture:

   `$lipo -info /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2/lib/libswscale.3.dylib`

output:

```
 Non-fat file: /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2/lib/libswscale.3.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

My machine architecture:

```
$uname -m
```

output:

```
x86_64
```

4. The symbols exist in the binary, for example:

   `$nm /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2/lib/libswscale.3.1.101.dylib | grep sws_alloc_context`

output:

```
000000000004e3b4 T _sws_alloc_context
```

5. I also tried a couple of different swscale binaries, not only the "brew" ones, but nothing changed. I also tried to do the same on my Ubuntu laptop, but it is still the same.

This is actually a QT app I'm trying to build. I should mention, that I don't have issues with linking other libraries the same way.
I also compiled successfully `swscale-test.c` (which is in libwscale sources) using:

```
clang swscale-test.c -lswscale -lavutil
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong or what else can I try to find out the reason?

Comment: have you included the necessary header files required for the swscale function you are using.

Comment: Is your application in C++? Also, is swscale library a C library?

Comment: @mSatyam, sure, otherwise I'd have a compiler errors, no linker ones

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not showing your code, but typically the problem is that you need `extern "C"` around ffmpeg #include statements when compiling c++ code (see [FAQ](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#I_0027m-using-FFmpeg-from-within-my-C_002b_002b-application-but-the-linker-complains-about-missing-symbols-which-seem-to-be-available_002e)):

```
extern "C" {
#include "libswscale/swscale.h"
}
```

The same goes for all other ffmpeg includes.

Comment: That is a great finding for me! I've never done that before when including a header because libraries always had that "extern "C"" thing in their headers to allow C++ linkers. I'm really surprised that ffmpeg doesn't have it and I didn't even notice. This is one more step to check now, when I come across such errors!

Comment: Whether to add extern "C" to the app or to the project headers is largely a political thing. FFmpeg is C, not C++, so some developers have strong objections to adding #ifdef __cplusplus guards in our code.